# How to incoperate responses from other webapps running in same Tomcat instance?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

In a running servlet request I need to request data from an other servlet of a different webapp running in the same Tomcat instance. Using new URL connections to the same Tomcat connector/port would work in general but it may run into deadlocks when max connection/threads ist reached.

I'm aware of the both methods *RequestDispatcher.forward()* and *RequestDispatcher.include()* in combination with Tomcat's *crossContext=true* option, but as far as I know, both methods are designed to work directly on the current *ServletResponse* instance which I don't want.

Are there alternatives to those two approaches? I thought of creating and passing new *ServletRequest* and *ServletResponse* instances to one of the both *RequestDispatcher* methods above, but I could not find examples on this so far.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Note: Making a new URL connection and `crossContext` have nothing to do with each other. More important: As you ask for "the best way": That's quite an opinionated question and depends on a lot of criteria that is not contained in your question. That's why opinionated questions are a reason for closing a question on stackoverflow. You might want to edit it to be less opinionated and more specific.

Comment: @OlafKock: Thank you for your valuable hints. I edited my question.